# Hibernate annotations to exclude fields in base class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, inheritance, annotations

I have a base class with four fields a,b,c & d and two sub classes which extend it.

I'm trying to ensure SubOne doesn't persist field d and SubTwo doesn't persist field c.

The xml mapping below works perfectly.

**Is this possible using annotations?**

(Hibernate v3.2.4, JPA 1.0)

```
public class Base {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private String d;   
}

public class SubOne extends Base {
    private int id;
}

public class SubTwo extends Base {
    private int id;
    private String e;
}
```

Mapping:

```
<class name="SubOne" table="SubOne">
    <id name="id" column="Id">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="a" column="a" />
    <property name="b" column="b" />
    <property name="c" column="c" />
</class>

<class name="SubTwo" table="SubTwo">
    <id name="id" column="Id">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="a" column="a" />
    <property name="b" column="b" />
    <property name="d" column="d" />
    <property name="e" column="e" />
</class>
```

SubOne Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SubOne")
public class SubOne extends Base implements Serializable {       

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String getA() {
    return super.getA();
}

@Override
public String getB() {
    return super.getB();
}

@Override
public String getC() {
    return super.getC();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it, but in an awkward way:

Override getter methods:

- getD in SubOne
- getC is SubTwo

Annotate these two methods as [@Transient](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help @orid.  I tried it but it's not working is this what you mean?  I put my code above

Comment: Thanks!!  I got it, the above seems to work.  One final question - how could I do it as field rather than methods?

Comment: Please disregard, shadowing fields is a bad idea.

Comment: I will - Thanks again. I was stuck all day with this!

Comment: Just realised I don't even need the `@Transient`, I just need to Override the methods I require from Base.

Comment: I am also trying the same, in Spring Boot, but unable to ignore columns using overriding getter method. Need more clarification on this. Thanks.